# Rescaling multivariable normal pdf and normalizing constant

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-distribution, jacobian

I am trying to understand change of variables for a random variable and how it changes the pdf and the normalizing constant.

Let $\mathbf{x}$ be $N$-dimensional normal variable and let $\mathbf{\Sigma_x}$ be covariance matrix which has been already diagonalized (So $\mathbf{x}$ has been already "rotated" by the eigenvectors). The pdf is

$$
P_x(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{\exp\{-\frac12 \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}_x} \mathbf{x}\}}{\int d\mathbf{x} \exp\{-\frac12 \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}_x} \mathbf{x}\}} = (2\pi)^{-N/2} (\det \mathbf{\Sigma_x})^{-\frac12} \exp\{-\frac12 \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}_x} \mathbf{x}\}
$$

Now I make the change of variable to $\mathbf{y} = a \mathbf{x}$ and calculate Jacobian. Function for change of variable is $g(x) = a x$ and $g^{-1}(y) = a^{-1} y$ so according to the changing variable method new pdf must be

$$
P_y(\mathbf{y}) = P_x(g^{-1}(y)) \begin{vmatrix} \frac{d g^{-1}(y)}{dy}\end{vmatrix}
$$

where $\begin{vmatrix} \frac{d g^{-1}(y)}{dy}\end{vmatrix}$ is Jacobian. For case of rescaling of the variable this is just $\begin{vmatrix} a^{-1}\end{vmatrix}$. So pdf for $y$ is

$$
P_y(\mathbf{y}) = (2\pi)^{-N/2} [\det (a\ \mathbf{\Sigma_x} \ a)]^{-\frac12} \exp\{-\frac12 \mathbf{y}^T \frac{\mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}_x}}{a^2} \mathbf{y}\} \\= a^{-N} (2\pi)^{-N/2} [\det (\mathbf{\Sigma_x})]^{-\frac12} \exp\{-\frac12 \mathbf{y}^T \frac{\mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}_x}}{a^2} \mathbf{y}\}
$$

Now I try to calculate this result by making substitution $\mathbf{x}=a^{-1}\mathbf{y}$ in $P_x(\mathbf{x})$, but I get different answer for the integral in normalizing constant.
$$
P_y(\mathbf{y}) = \frac{\exp\{-\frac12 \mathbf{y}^T \frac{\mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}_x}}{a^2} \mathbf{y}\}}{\int d\mathbf{y} a^{-N} \exp\{-\frac12 \mathbf{y}^T \frac{\mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}_x}}{a^2} \mathbf{y}\}}
$$

The denominator above is normalizing constant and is a gauss integral
$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{N}&=a^{-N} \int d\mathbf{y}\exp\{-\frac12 \mathbf{y}^T \frac{\mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}_x}}{a^2} \mathbf{y}\} = a^{-N} (2\pi)^{N/2} [\det a^2 \mathbf{\Sigma_x}]^{1/2} \\&= a^{-N}a^{N} (2\pi)^{N/2} [\det \mathbf{\Sigma_x}]^{1/2} = (2\pi)^{N/2} [\det \mathbf{\Sigma_x}]^{1/2}
\end{align}
$$
So the $a$ is cancelling out here and new pdf is
$$
P_y(\mathbf{y}) = (2\pi)^{-N/2} [\det (\mathbf{\Sigma_x})]^{-\frac12} \exp\{-\frac12 \mathbf{y}^T \frac{\mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}_x}}{a^2} \mathbf{y}\}
$$

I don't understand why this is different from answer I got when using Jacobian formula? I must have made mistakes in the integral. Thank you.

Comment: Also asked at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3763624/321264.

Comment: Sorry for that, is it ok to ask on both sites?

Comment: After "so the pdf for $y$ is," you have replaced $\Sigma_x$ by $a \Sigma_x a.$  What rule justifies that??

Comment: @whuber For that I combine the determinants: Jacobian is $|a^{-1}|$ so $|a^{-1}| |\Sigma_a|^{-1/2}=|a^{-1}|^{1/2} |\Sigma_a|^{-1/2} |a^{-1}|^{1/2} = |a \Sigma_a\ a|^{-1/2}$. Is this not correct?

Comment: But you kept the factor of $a^{-N}$ in the expression.  You have in effect incorporated the Jacobian and, at the same time, undone that work.  Try writing it all out explicitly in the case of one dimension: that ought to make the correct algebra more obvious.

Comment: @whuber Yes I wrote that in unclear way. The expression in front of exponential in $P_y(\mathbf{y})$ is $ a^{-N} (2\pi)^{-N/2} [\det (\mathbf{\Sigma_x})]^{-\frac12}$. My confusion is why making substitution $\mathbf{x} = a^{-1} \mathbf{y}$ in the normalizing constant integral does not give same result: the $a^{-N}$ is cancelling out. For one dimension variable, $a$ is also cancelling out of integral. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You persist in modifying $\Sigma_x$ in the variable substitution, but that's invalid.

Comment: Sorry I am still little bit confused. In what step is it invalid? I thought making substitution $\mathbf{x}=a^{-1} \mathbf{y}$ means that $\exp\{ x^T \Sigma_x x \}$ becomes $\exp\{ y^T a^{-2}\Sigma_x y \}$. Is this what you mean by modifying $\Sigma_x$ which is invalid?

Comment: There is mistake in my previous comment, $\Sigma_x$ should be $\Sigma^{-1}_x$

Comment: Answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3763624/rescaling-multivariable-normal-pdf-and-normalizing-constant